# Error in getting value from textviews in getIntent.getParcelableExtra

Tags: java, android, search, themoviedb-api

I was working with android project these days, and It will finish soon, but I got stuck in my project. First, I want to create search activity which will be used for searching movies. The searching activity runs well, but whenever it comes to adding the selected movie, it shown me the error code below:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.example.idstream.pojo.Movies.setTitle(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
>           at com.example.idstream.search.MoviesDetailActivity.addFavorite(MoviesDetailActivity.java:96)
>           at com.example.idstream.search.MoviesDetailActivity.access$100(MoviesDetailActivity.java:19)
>           at com.example.idstream.search.MoviesDetailActivity$1.onClick(MoviesDetailActivity.java:78)

This code has an error in this area:

```
Movies movies = getIntent().getParcelableExtra(EXTRA_TITLE);
movies.setTitle(getIntent().getStringExtra(EXTRA_TITLE));
movies.setRelease_info(getIntent().getStringExtra(EXTRA_RELEASE));
movies.setLanguage(getIntent().getStringExtra(EXTRA_LANGUAGE));
movies.setDescription(getIntent().getStringExtra(EXTRA_OVERVIEW));
movies.setPhotos(getIntent().getStringExtra(EXTRA_PHOTOS));
```

I've tried to add the selected movie to database in other activity, but it didn't mention any error. But when I tried to save the selected movie to database, it turns out an error. I also tried to send it to a toast, which I wanna make sure whether the value that I sent was successfully retrieved. The toast is successfully get the data.

**Here is my SearchFragment.java:**

```
public class SearchMovieFragment extends Fragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<ArrayList<Movies>>  {

ListView lvMovieItems;
EditText txtTitleMovieInput;
ImageView imgMoviesSearch;
Button btnSearchMovie;
AdaptersMovie adaptersMovie;
MovieHelper movieHelper;
Boolean act = true;
Boolean insert = true;
Boolean delete = true;
private View mView;

public SearchMovieFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search_movie, container, false);
    txtTitleMovieInput   = (EditText)mView.findViewById(R.id.txtMovieTitle);
    String mTitles = txtTitleMovieInput.getText().toString();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString(EXTRA_MOVIE, mTitles);

    imgMoviesSearch   = (ImageView)mView.findViewById(R.id.imgMovies);
    btnSearchMovie     = (Button) mView.findViewById(R.id.btn_search);

    btnSearchMovie.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String mTitleMovie = txtTitleMovieInput.getText().toString();
            if(TextUtils.isEmpty(mTitleMovie)){
                return;
            }
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString(EXTRA_MOVIE, mTitleMovie);
            getLoaderManager().restartLoader(0, bundle, SearchMovieFragment.this);
        }
    });

    getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, bundle, SearchMovieFragment.this);
    adaptersMovie     = new AdaptersMovie(getActivity());
    adaptersMovie.notifyDataSetChanged();
    lvMovieItems    = (ListView)mView.findViewById(R.id.listMovies);
    lvMovieItems.setAdapter(adaptersMovie);
    lvMovieItems.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Movies item = (Movies)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MoviesDetailActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(MoviesDetailActivity.EXTRA_MOVIE, item.getTitle());
            intent.putExtra(MoviesDetailActivity.EXTRA_RELEASE, item.getRelease_info());
            intent.putExtra(MoviesDetailActivity.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, item.getLanguage());
            intent.putExtra(MoviesDetailActivity.EXTRA_OVERVIEW, item.getDescription());
            intent.putExtra(MoviesDetailActivity.EXTRA_PHOTOS, item.getPhotos());
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    return mView;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public Loader<ArrayList<Movies>> onCreateLoader(int id, @Nullable Bundle args) {
    String temp = "";
    if (args != null){
        temp = args.getString(EXTRA_MOVIE);
    }
    return new MovieAsyncTaskLoader(getActivity(), temp);
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(@NonNull Loader<ArrayList<Movies>> loader, ArrayList<Movies> data) {
    adaptersMovie.setData(data);
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(@NonNull Loader<ArrayList<Movies>> loader) {
    adaptersMovie.setData(null);
}
```

}

My MoviesDetailActivity.java:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_movies_detail);

    setTitle("Movie's Details");
    tvTitles = findViewById(R.id.movieTitles);
    tvReleased = findViewById(R.id.movieRelease);
    tvLanguages = findViewById(R.id.movieLanguages);
    tvDescription = findViewById(R.id.movieDescriptions);
    imageMovies = findViewById(R.id.moviesImage);
    progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressMovie);
    fav_moviesBtn = findViewById(R.id.fab_movie);
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    String mvTitles = getIntent().getStringExtra(EXTRA_MOVIE);
    String mvLanguages = getIntent().getStringExtra(EXTRA_LANGUAGE);
    String mvOverview = getIntent().getStringExtra(EXTRA_OVERVIEW);
    String mvRelease = getIntent().getStringExtra(EXTRA_RELEASE);
    String mvPhotos = getIntent().getStringExtra(EXTRA_PHOTOS);

    tvTitles.setText(mvTitles);
    tvReleased.setText(mvRelease);
    tvLanguages.setText(mvLanguages);
    tvDescription.setText(mvOverview);
    Glide.with(MoviesDetailActivity.this)
            .load("https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185" + mvPhotos)
            .placeholder(R.color.colorFreshOrange)
            .dontAnimate()
            .into(imageMovies);

    movieHelper = new MovieHelper(MoviesDetailActivity.this);
    movieHelper.open();

    mMoviess = getIntent().getIntExtra(FAVOURITE,0);

    fav_moviesBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (!isAdd) {
                addFavorite();
                Toast.makeText(MoviesDetailActivity.this, "Berhasil Ditambahkan", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                fav_moviesBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher_fav_yes_24_foreground);
            } else {
                removeFavorite();
                Toast.makeText(MoviesDetailActivity.this, "Berhasil Dihapuskan", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                fav_moviesBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher_fav_no_24_foreground);
            }
        }
    });

    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

}


private void addFavorite() {
    Movies movies = getIntent().getParcelableExtra(EXTRA_TITLE);
    movies.setTitle(getIntent().getStringExtra(EXTRA_TITLE));
    movies.setRelease_info(getIntent().getStringExtra(EXTRA_RELEASE));
    movies.setLanguage(getIntent().getStringExtra(EXTRA_LANGUAGE));
    movies.setDescription(getIntent().getStringExtra(EXTRA_OVERVIEW));
    movies.setPhotos(getIntent().getStringExtra(EXTRA_PHOTOS));
    movieHelper.insertMovie(movies);
}

private void removeFavorite() {

    Movies movies = new Movies();
    movies.setTitle(getIntent().getStringExtra(EXTRA_TITLE));
    movies.setRelease_info(getIntent().getStringExtra(EXTRA_RELEASE));
    movies.setLanguage(getIntent().getStringExtra(EXTRA_LANGUAGE));
    movies.setDescription(getIntent().getStringExtra(EXTRA_OVERVIEW));
    movies.setPhotos(getIntent().getStringExtra(EXTRA_PHOTOS));
    movieHelper.deleteMovie(getIntent().getStringExtra(EXTRA_MOVIE));
}
```

}

**And this one is my MovieHelper.java:**

```
public Boolean getOne(String name){
    String querySingleRecord = "SELECT * FROM " + DATABASE_TABLE + " WHERE " +DatabaseContract.MovieColoumn.TITLE+ " " + " LIKE " +"'"+name+"'" ;
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(querySingleRecord,null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    Log.d("cursor", String.valueOf(cursor.getCount()));
    if (cursor.getCount() > 0 ){
        return true;
    }else if(cursor.getCount() == 0){
        return false;
    }
    return false;
}

public long insertMovie(Movies mMovies){
    ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
    args.put(IDS,mMovies.getId());
    args.put(DatabaseContract.MovieColoumn.TITLE,mMovies.getTitle());
    args.put(DatabaseContract.MovieColoumn.RELEASE_INFO,mMovies.getRelease_info());
    args.put(DatabaseContract.MovieColoumn.LANGUAGE,mMovies.getLanguage());
    args.put(DatabaseContract.MovieColoumn.DESCRIPTION,mMovies.getDescription());
    args.put(DatabaseContract.MovieColoumn.PHOTOS,mMovies.getPhotos());
    return database.insert(DATABASE_TABLE,null,args);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is here:

> ```
> Movies movies = getIntent().getParcelableExtra(EXTRA_TITLE);
> movies.setTitle(getIntent().getStringExtra(EXTRA_TITLE));
> ```

Notice that you're using the same `EXTRA_TITLE` for both.

I think that what's happening is that `getParcelableExtra()` is returning `null`, because the implementation of `Bundle` (the extras) will catch the `ClassCastException`:

> ```
> // ...
> try {
>     return (T) o;
> } catch (ClassCastException e) {
>     typeWarning(key, o, "Parcelable", e);
>     return null;
> }
> ```

And then you get a `NullPointerException` when you try to call `setTitle()`.

Instead, create a new `Movies` instance yourself:

```
Movies movies = new Movies();
movies.setTitle(getIntent().getStringExtra(EXTRA_TITLE));
```

Alternatively, you could implement the `Parcelable` interface in your `Movies` class, and then you wouldn't have to bother adding all of its fields one by one.

Comment: I've tried the " Movies movies = new Movies();" It didnt show any error, but the data is not stored to db

Comment: Okay btw, it already works, thank you Mr.Ben for answering My question. I've figured out what happened to my class.